# SQL SELECT Date based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, date, conditional-statements, case

I have a set of date in a Table which contains weekly date.

I want to select the following:

If the date is **less** than 2 months old then i want to select all the date (weekly).

If the date is **more** than 2 months old then i only want to select the last date of each month (monthly).

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Date) FROM [Table] WHERE Date IN 
(CASE 
WHEN Date> DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) 
THEN Date 
ELSE MAX(Date) GROUP BY Month(Date),Year(Date)
);
```

But without success:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

If for instance the current Date is 13/09/2022,

13/09/2022 - 2 months = 13/07/2022

If i have the following Date in my Table:

- 06/05/2022

  13/05/2022

  20/05/2022

  31/05/2022

  07/06/2022

  10/06/2022

  17/06/2022

  24/06/2022

  30/06/2022

  08/07/2022 (<13/07/2022)

  15/07/2022 (>13/07/2022)

  22/07/2022

  29/07/2022

  05/08/2022

  12/08/2022

  19/08/2022

  26/08/2022

Then the final output should be:

- 31/05/2022

  30/06/2022 (<13/07/2022)

  15/07/2022 (>13/07/2022)

  22/07/2022

  29/07/2022

  05/08/2022

  12/08/2022

  19/08/2022

  26/08/2022

Comment: You have no `END` for your `CASE` expression, and you are also trying to use an aggregate function in the `WHERE` (which is not allowed). The `IN` against a single scalar value doesn't make any sense either; it should be an `=`.

Comment: You also appear to believe that `DISTINCT` is a function, not a set operation. Though a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Comment: In truth, sample data and expected results would really help us help you here.

Comment: I know what the current date is, @Alan . Not sure what your point is.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results from that sample data. We are tripping up trying to backwards engineer your error filled and incorrect SQL to figure out what you really meant to do.

Comment: There is an [edit] feature, @Alan .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is completely invalid, I'm not going to bother fixing it.

- `DISTINCT` is not a function, it works over the whole set of columns.
- You can't use aggregates inside a `WHERE`, even if they would be window functions (which they're not).
- The `GROUP BY` is inside a `CASE` which makes no sense.

Instead I'm just going off your requirements

- If the date is less than 2 months old then I want to select all the date (weekly).
- If the date is more than 2 months old then I only want to select the last date of each month (monthly).

You can use a `ROW_NUMBER` strategy for this.

```sql
SELECT
  t.Date
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EOMONTH(t.Date) ORDER BY t.Date DESC)
    FROM [Table] t
) t
WHERE (
   t.Date > DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
   OR rn = 1
)
ORDER BY
  Date;
```

Comment: This works as long as you have end of month date (EOMONTH function), the reason why i used MAX(Date) GROUP BY Month(Date),Year(Date) is to get the last date available per month in the set of date instead of the last date per month.
For instance if 30/08/2022 is in my set of date but 31/08/2022 isn't, i won't get 30/08/2022 since EOMONTH will return 31/08/2022.

Comment: That's not how that works. It's *partitioning* the data by a calculated value giving the month-end for each row, therefore it will return `rn = 1` for the last row in each month, no matter what your data is. See eg https://dbfiddle.uk/Wy30YvEz where you can see what happens in such a dataset